# Getting issue with alias of two domains

Tags: dns, cname

I have a website on
**test1.abc.com** domain
and I want to show that website on
**test2.xyz.com** using CNAME so anyone have an idea that how to do that

Comment: This is first of all an issue of server configuration. The virtual host for `test1.abc.com` needs to list `test2.xyz.com` as an alias domain, so that the server knows where to route incoming requests with the `test2.xyz.com` host name.

Comment: Additional configuration of your app _might_ be necessary, if that decides which content to serve based on the request host name.

Comment: This is for serverfault.stackexchange.com not for Stack Overflow